# Facebook Open Graph Story - Publishing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on setting up Open Graph Story publishing for my App and all of the tutorials I have seen require asking the user for permissions for your App to post on their timeline which isn't what I want. I want to allow the user to choose if they want to post the content on their timeline, not give my App permission to auto post content whenever I want. I know that I as well as many other people will not use any App that asks for such permissions.

I know that sharing a link such as

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

doesn't need the *publish_action* permission, it is simply a popup that the user can confirm or decline whether or not they want to share the link, so my question is can the Open Graph Story stuff be done in this same manner?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook recently introduced a new [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) which allows the sharing of Open Graph stories **without** the `publish_actions` permission.

What this means is that the only thing you'll need to submit for approval is the custom story you've created. (If your story is custom and not one of the built-in actions)